# What is another way to say "Wake Up"?

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms, idiom-requests

What is a phrase that describes waking up mentally or a mental *wake up call*?

You say,

> I know, I know. I need to do this, that and the other, so I had better  _________

to achieve your goals, but instead you remain in your comfort zone ... Wake Up!

"Wake up!" I think is overused and antiquated. I am looking for a fresh phrase that means something like to stop procrastinating.

Comment: "Snap out of it"?

Comment: "so its is time to shake myself up" ?

Comment: I think Snap Out of It .....could work.. "Snap out of your comfort zone and Snap to pursuing  Your Dream Worth Failing For"   It implies coming out of a dozing or unfocused state as well. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

**Pull your finger out** means to stop prevaricating and start to act.

or a similar phrase with a slightly different meaning which could apply is:

**Pull your socks up** which means to make an effort to improve your performance/behaviour.

Comment: The first one is often in the form of "Pull your finger out of your #$%^".

Answer (score 1):

**Snap out of (something)** — [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/snap-out-of-it)

> To stop experiencing something unpleasant or stop behaving in a negative way
> *"I was depressed, and I couldn't snap out of it."*
> *"Johnson has finally snapped out of a four-week hitting slump."*

**Come alive** (or come to life) — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+alive)

> 1. Become vigorous or lively.
>
> *"It took some fast rhythms to make the dancers come alive."*
> *"As soon as he mentioned ice cream, the children came to life."*
>
> The adjective alive has been used in the sense of "vivacious"

**Come around** — [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/come-round)

> C1. to become conscious again after an accident or operation
> *"She hasn't come round from the anaesthetic yet."*

Answer (score 0):

> I know, I know. I need to do this, that and the other, so I had better **stop cutting bait.**

This derives from the idiomatic expression "*Are you going to fish or cut bait?*", meaning "Are you going to get anything done, or just sit around procrastinating?"

Answer (score 0):

> I know, I know. I need to do this, that and the other, so I had better
>   **focus**

The implication is that until this moment your mind was wandering but now you need to concentrate on the task at hand without distraction.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is ***get started*** (and it's synonyms from TFD below).

> I know, I know. I need to do this, that and the other, so I had better
>   ***get started***.

[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/get+started):

> *Verb*    1.  **get started** - start to be active; "Get cracking, please!"
>
> **get cracking, get moving, get rolling, get weaving, get going**